# Android: determinine my app's process ID?

Tags: java, android, pid

Is there a way within a java app that's running under Android to determine that app's process ID ("PID")?

The reason I want this is that I am writing an app which reads and processes lines from logcat, and I want to be able to ignore all logcat lines that have been written by this app, itself.

I know I can do this by using a unique tag for my app in all the Log.*() calls and then ignoring logcat lines with this tag, but it seems to me that it would be cleaner if I could simply ignore all logcat lines which have been written by my own app's PID.

I've searched, but I couldn't find anything which explains how to determine the PID of a running Android app, from within that app, itself.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or pointers to docs.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You're looking for [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#myPid()), I think:

```
int id = android.os.Process.myPid();
```

Comment: Yep, that's it! Thank you. I missed this because I was looking within java.lang.Process and not android.os.process.